# bad interpreter: Permission denied in shell scripting ls ubuntu

Tags: linux, shell

I am quite new to the shell scripting.
So I am writing the shell script to list all files available in the directory using ls command.

but I am getting the error bad interpreter: Permission denied

```
#!/home/gaurav

echo "Welcome bash shell scripting"
ls
echo "this complets the listing of directories"
```

I want to get the list of "/home/gaurav" this path

Thanks

Comment: Your shebang line is wrong - it's meant to be a path to the shell you want to use, e.g. `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line...

```
#!/home/gaurav
```

... means "instead of using `/bin/bash`, use `/home/guarav` as the program to run this file". This is not what you want. What you want is either:

```
cd /home/gaurav # at the top, or
ls /home/gaurav # between echoes
```

Comment: hay can anybody suggest me a good website to learn Shell Scripting,,,,,,,,, Please

Answer (score 2):

Problem is this line:

```
#!/home/gaurav
```

This is called shebang and it should be the bash/shell interpreter like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

one that interprets and executes your script. Since `/home/gaurav` is not a valid interpreter you're getting that error.

You probably want this in your script:

```
ls /home/gaurav
```

to list all files/directories in `/home/gaurav` path.

Answer (score 2):

Either add #!/bin/bash or #!/bin/sh instead of #!/home/gaurav line while starting script.

Because, while running shell script, you have to give path of which bash or sh are you going to run to execute that script.